# Hide Until Needed Header Not Working On Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Not sure if this is a CSS issue or a JS issue, but I've been working on a website (TheFilmPoets.com) that uses a header navigation container that is "hidden until needed".  In other words the navigation menu doesn't show until you scroll up.  It works perfectly on the desktop but on the mobile and tablet version of the site it doesn't work.

Does anyone have any direction as to whether it's a CSS or JS issue or how to resolve the matter?

Comment: I think it's partly because the #header-outer element's `data-mobile-fixed="true"`.  When I set it to `data-mobile-fixed="false"`, the menu visaully appears to work on devices with a screen width between approximately 765px and 1000px. It still does not work on devices with a width smaller than approximately 765px.

Comment: Looking at it some more, the menu does not work perfectly when `data-mobile-fixed="false"`. When the menu is expanded, the expanded menu always appears at the top of the page.

Answer (score 1):

You have this CSS rule which hides the header on screens with width <= 768px:

(inline on line 30)

```
#header-space, #header-outer {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: That hides the header on the homepage, but it's present on the other pages.